# Wrong values in winfo_height/width after Label.configure(text=)

Tags: python, tkinter

In Python 3.5.0 using Tkinter on IDLE Python on Windows, I'm attempting to do some hover text (like alt-text on images in a web browser) that follows the mouse cursor over a variety of thumbnails, which have various length text in each.

Since the mouse could get close to the edge of the window and cause the text to go off the edge of the viewable space, I want to move it based on if the text would go off.

But I'm seeing that after I call configure(text=) on my label, it will sometimes return the old height/width values of the Label.  I've tried adding .after(), but that doesn't seem to do anything.

```
def onEnter(self, event): # called by .bind("<Enter>", self.onEnter)
  print(time.time(), self.name, "onEnter")
  hoverlabel.config(text=self.name)
  self.onMove(event) # use the move event for code-reuse

def onMove(self, event): # called by .bind("<Motion>", self.onMove)
  # get the mouse's location on the current window
  win = hoverlabel.winfo_toplevel()
  winx = win.winfo_rootx()
  winy = win.winfo_rooty()
  xpos = event.x_root - winx
  ypos = event.y_root - winy

  # get the size of the text
  texth = hoverlabel.winfo_height()
  textw = hoverlabel.winfo_width()

  # This will sometimes print old values!
  print(time.time(), self.name, "onMove", textw, texth)

  # determine if the text would run off the edge
  EXTRA = 5 # a few extra pixels to eliminate some grossness
  if xpos + textw + EXTRA >= win.winfo_width():
      xpos = xpos - textw

  if ypos + (texth*2) >= win.winfo_height():
      ypos = ypos - texth
  else:
      ypos = ypos + texth

  hoverlabel.place(anchor=Tk.NW, x=xpos, y=ypos)
```

Output sometimes:

```
1509771933.4276707 Tsuro of the Seas onMove 96 21
1509771933.4414082 Tsuro of the Seas onMove 96 21
1509771933.4548104 Tsuro of the Seas onLeave
1509771933.4618150 Blood Rage: 5th Player Expansi onEnter
1509771933.4711444 Blood Rage: 5th Player Expansi onMove 96 21
1509771933.4831665 Blood Rage: 5th Player Expansi onMove 180 21
1509771933.4951801 Blood Rage: 5th Player Expansi onMove 180 21
```

We see that in the transition from Tsuro to Blood Rage, it waits until the second onMove to update, which is the next time I move the mouse.

What can I do? What's the trick I'm not aware of to delay until after Tk updates? I'm planning to eventually embed images in the label that will buffer from the internet, so it'd be great to get this weird text delay sorted...

Edit: "old values of text" --> "old height/width values of the Label"

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this in my own program, but try using `widget.update()` after you called the `.configure()`. See if that helps at all?

Comment: I want to say I tried that, and that it didn't help. That said, I found that at the time I wasn't actually calling .mainloop(), and that the entire thing worked by some flukey miracle of IDLE Python. The problem does still happen even now though, but I also removed the update(). I'll throw it in later.

Summary: It's worth a shot and I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Let me know how it works out for you, I'm happy to try and help you get this fixed

Comment: Alas, adding .update() didn't fix it. I'll see if I can make a trivial example that has this behavior.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 running 3.6.2 in the Python IDLE. If I can replicate this, I'm happy to have a look. I'm interested as to what seems to be causing this.

Comment: I wrote a minimal version, and since adding the .update DID seem to fix it... that might be it..?

Comment: Except, in my project, I've already got the .update in there, and still seem to be having the issue. Oy.